# In C, I would like to print 4 decimal numbers in a row and then print the next 4

Tags: c, printf

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    int max = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If `max` is `1000` then this will print in the format shown below

```
0123 up to 1000
```

But I would like to print 4 values per line as shown below:

```
0123   
4567
...
```

I would like to see the numbers not the just the digits. for a single digit numbers, it should be like this: `0123` for two digit numbers, it should be like this: `11121314` for a three digit numbers, it should be like this: `111112113114` up to `996997998999` up to `1000`.

Comment: Print a space if `i` is divisible by 4.

Comment: Your own sample code will not print the leading `0`.

Comment: Do you mean 4 decimal digits per line?

Comment: Can you expand a little bit your expected output?

Comment: @Santhosh: can you answer my question? There is a difference between digits (`0`, `1` ... `9`) and numbers that can have one or more digits.  Your question is ambiguous as correctly written.

Comment: @chqrlie I have modified the code and I would like to see the numbers not the just the digits. 
for a single digit numbers, it should be like this: 
 0123
for two digit numbers, it should be like this:
 11121314
for a three digit numbers, it should be like this:
 111112113114
up to 
 996997998999

Hope this is clear. This is my first time at stack overflow. If I am not clear, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For your loop to print upto and including `1000` for `max.size = 1000`, you must use the `<=` operator.

Here is a modified version that will format the output with a maximum of 4 characters per line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    struct { int size; } max = { 1000 };

    if (max.size >= 0) {
        for (int col = 0, i = 0;; i++) {
            char buf[2 + sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT / 3];
            int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", i);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                putchar(buf[j]);
                if (++col == 4) {
                   putchar('\n');
                   col = 0;
                }
            }
            if (i == max.size) {
                if (col > 0) {
                    putchar('\n');
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will print:

```
0123
4567
8910
1112
1718
...
6997
9989
9910
00
```

**EDIT**

From your updated question, it is actually much simpler: print a linefeed character after every 4th number, using the modulo operator `%`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int max = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        printf("%d", i);
        if (i % 4 == 3)
            putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: true. fixed with a generic somewhat pedantic formula. Note that using `snprintf` prevents UB, but the output would indeed be incorrect for values of `max.size >= 1000000000`.

Comment: For that matter, it can not be executed until INT_MAX(talk about `max.size == INT_MAX`). (me too :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: The loop would indeed invoke undefined behavior if `max.size = INT_MAX`, but it could certainly run all the way until `INT_MAX-1`, generating many GB of output (precisely 25,454,656,700  bytes)

Comment: yes, start with `i = INT_MAX -1` (Do not caught so much serious.;-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: OK, for completeness, rather than seriousness, I updated the code so it has defined behavior even for `max.size == INT_MAX`.

Comment: I think this answer is that it is the best. (I have already done upvote this.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: thank you, but for some reason, someone silently downvoted all answers.

Comment: I don't know the reason for downvote. it is possible to cancel my upvote if you doubt.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Dont, 1UV + 1DV = +8, still quite positive.  For those who wonder how you can tell upvotes and downvotes, click on the score to see both counts.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether `i+1` is divisible by 4 or not. Whenever it is divisible by 4, print a newline.

```
for (int i = 0; i < max.size; ++i) {

     printf("%d", i);
     if((i+1)%4 == 0)
         printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to fit the OP's goal.

Comment: @chqrlie honestly, OP's goal is not very clear to me.

Comment: I agree.  From his examples, its seems he wants 4 digits per line, instead of 4 numbers.

Comment: @Bob__ : Yes, i have tested it. I am not sure, if OP wants to print four digit per line of four integer per line.

Comment: @chqrlie : From his example. we can only make assumptions.

Comment: @chqrlie, Bob__, Shravan40: and there is a close reason for that. The OP must clarify it.

Comment: @Shravan40: I don't know who the silent downvoter is, doing this without commenting is bad practice.

Comment: @chqrlie: I bet it's from someone who **strongly** objects against answering unclear questions. (Actually I do that as well, but not to the extend of down voting answers! :) I'd rather point out that it is useless until the OP clarifies.)

Comment: @RadLexus: the question was unclear and my guesses were off.  Things are usually much simpler than they look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using a buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_digit(int number);

int main(void) {
    putchar('0');
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        print_digit(i);
    }
}

void print_digit(int number) {
    static int digit_count = 1; // a zero is already printed
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= number; i *= 10);
    for(i /= 10; i; i /= 10) {
        putchar('0' + number % (i * 10) / i);
        digit_count++;
        if(digit_count == 4) {
            digit_count = 0;
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have to admit that this code has nothing to do with elegance, because I don't know how to make `print_digit` consistent with zero.